# Google maps apiv3 multipolygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a visualization which uses the apiv3 for Google Maps. Currently I am mapping a few thousand polygons on a map and some markers as well. The problem is that some of the areas I am attempting to draw are considered "multipolygons". For example a voting district which has multiple areas which are separated and not connected in a single polygon. How do I draw this?

Tried this but it didnt seem to render.

```
var Poly14591; 
var outer = new google.maps.MVCArray([new google.maps.LatLng( 42.862496, -78.151154), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.862251, -78.151319), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.86189, -78.151538), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.861765, -78.151647)]);


var inner = new google.maps.MVCArray([new google.maps.LatLng( 42.867545, -78.151817), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.866978, -78.151813), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.866044, -78.151787), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.864956, -78.151712), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.864231, -78.151709), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.863593, -78.151708)]);

var paths = new google.maps.MVCArray([outer, inner]);

Poly14591 = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:paths,  strokeOpacity: 10.0, strokeWeight: 20, strokeColor: "#FF0000", fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.35}); 

 Poly14591.setMap(map);
```

Comment: [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) objects take an array of paths.

Comment: so it looks like I need to use MVCArray? Are there any samples of it?

Comment: You don't have to use MVCArrays, a normal array of arrays of google.maps.LatLng objects works.  I have examples at http://www.geocodezip.com, but most of the examples involve holes not separate regions, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This actually seemed to allow me to map separate polygons which are actually still in the context of a single google maps polygon object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polygon</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var bermudaTriangle;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

var Poly14591; 


  var paths = [[new google.maps.LatLng( 42.862496, -78.151154), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.862251, -78.151319), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.86189, -78.151538), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.861765, -78.151647)], [new google.maps.LatLng( 42.867545, -78.151817), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.866978, -78.151813), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.866044, -78.151787), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.864956, -78.151712), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.864231, -78.151709), new google.maps.LatLng( 42.863593, -78.151708)]];


Poly14591 = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:paths,  strokeOpacity: 10.0, strokeWeight: 20, strokeColor: "#FF0000", fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.35}); 

 Poly14591.setMap(map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```